# Animating a border color

Tags: jquery, animation

I have an element with a black border that I want to make it "pulse". I am approaching this with `.animate()` but I cant seem to get the results I want. I made a fiddle but for some reason nothing is working on it yet on my dev the animation works initially. The border gets set to transparent and that is it. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dSh97/2/) is the fiddle. Thanks

Comment: You keep writing `bordeColor`...

Comment: The blinking may trigger seizures if it is too fast

Comment: The animation will go for about a min then Ill clear the interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check `border-top-color/left/right/bottom` for IE - also border color returns rgb color code.  Last thing you need is to include jQuery UI.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      var $el = $('#live-feed-wrapper div:first-child');
      // if not black then make black
      if ($el.css('border-top-color').replace(/\s/g,'') != 'rgb(0,0,0)') {
        $el.animate({'borderColor': 'black'});
      }
      else {
        $el.animate({'borderColor': 'transparent'});
      }
    },500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QM9QT/

Answer (score 2):

For color animation You need to use [jQueryUi](http://jqueryui.com/) or [color plugin](http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.0.min.js)

```
var $el = $('#live-feed-wrapper div:first-child');
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if ($el.data('toggle')) {
        $el.animate({
            'borderColor': 'black'
        });
        $el.data('toggle', false);
    } else {
        $el.animate({
            'borderColor': 'transparent'
        });
        $el.data('toggle', true);
    }
}, 500);
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/dSh97/8/

Comment: That is what is happening on my site. Like your demo it does not pulse.

Answer (score 2):

No need for jQuery, pure CSS works just fine:

```css
#live-feed-wrapper div:first-child {
    animation: pulse 0.5s linear infinite alternate;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 0.5s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes pulse {
    from {border-color:black}
    to {border-color:transparent}
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    from {border-color:black}
    to {border-color:transparent}
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dSh97/3/)

Comment: @roasted So? It's eye-candy.

Comment: The reason Im using jquery is because i will need to clear the interval.

Comment: @LouieV Set `elem.style.animation = 'none';` to stop the animation.

Comment: @Kolink Not working on IE 10 is going to be a deal breaker, since this will be part of a comercial application :(